# Youtube API 2 Python Setting Video Privacy

Tags: python, youtube-api, privacy

I've been tasked with finding a way to change our company's video privacy settings from private to public.  The reason for this is that we originally upload the videos as private, but at a certain time we publish the videos, and at that time they need to be made public.  I have found that in Java there is a method called something like this:

VideoEntry.YouTubeMediaGroup.setPrivate(boolean)

I haven't been able to find a similar method to this in the python interface.  Does anyone know if there is a way to do change the privacy settings for videos using the python interface to the youtube api version 2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to change a video from private to public using the python interface to youtube.

**First we get the entry:**

entry = yt_service.GetYouTubeVideoEntry('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads/%s' % video_id)

**Next we remove the string `'<ns1:private />'` and create a new entry from the new string**:

`match = re.search('(.*)(<ns1:private />)(.*)', str(entry))`

`newentry = gdata.youtube.YouTubeVideoEntryFromString(match.group(1)+match.group(3))`

**Finally we update the entry on youtube:**

yt_service.UpdateVideoEntry(newentry)